# Laravel pagination with API resources

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel pagination has different structure when returned by itself vs. through an API resource.

```php
return $query->paginate(request('per_page'));
```

returns pagination with this structure:

```
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data":[...],
    "first_page_url": "http://user-service.test/api/users?page=1",
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "last_page_url": "http://user-service.test/api/users?page=1",
    "next_page_url": null,
    "path": "http://user-service.test/api/users",
    "per_page": 15,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "to": 10,
    "total": 10
}
```

On the other hand, sending the paginator through an API resource like this:

```php
return new UserCollection($query->paginate(request('per_page')));
```

returns this structure:

```
{
"data":[...],
"links": {
    "first": "http://user-service.test/api/users/searches?page=1",
    "last": "http://user-service.test/api/users/searches?page=6",
    "prev": null,
    "next": "http://user-service.test/api/users/searches?page=2"
    },
"meta": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 6,
    "path": "http://user-service.test/api/users/searches",
    "per_page": "1",
    "to": 1,
    "total": 6
    }
}
```

I need to have the same structure for both types. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

After some digging I found a solution for this, hope it's helpful.

So this line is fine

`return new UserCollection($query->paginate(request('per_page')));`

As long as you change the UserCollection toArray() function to:

```
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'current_page' => $this->currentPage(),
            'data' => $this->collection->toArray(),
            'first_page_url' => $this->url(1),
            'from' => $this->firstItem(),
            'last_page' => $this->lastPage(),
            'last_page_url' => $this->url($this->lastPage()),
            'next_page_url' => $this->nextPageUrl(),
            'path' => $this->path(),
            'per_page' => $this->perPage(),
            'prev_page_url' => $this->previousPageUrl(),
            'to' => $this->lastItem(),
            'total' => $this->total(),
        ];
    }
```

This snippet of code is from the original implementation of LengthAwarePaginator, this way you could have consistent pagination for both collections and simple use of LengthAwarePaginator (->paginate() function).

Answer (score 0):

That's because you created an [Eloquent Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#resource-collections).

As you can see in the doc, it's taking `$this->collection` and wraps it around a customer format.

If you wish to have the same format, you do not need to return the `UserCollection`, just return `$query->paginate(request('per_page'))`

Without seeing more of your code and how are you using your `UserCollection` class, it's hard to recommend to keep it or remove it. Also, please read the high overview of that concept [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#concept-overview)

Answer (score 0):

just do this

```
public function __construct($resource)
{
    $this->pagination = [
        'total' => $resource->total(),
        'per_page' => $resource->perPage(),
        'current_page' => $resource->currentPage(),
        'last_page' => $resource->lastPage(),
        'from' => $resource->firstItem(),
        'to' => $resource->lastItem(),
        'count' => $resource->count(),
        'total_pages' => $resource->lastPage()
    ];

    $resource = $resource->getCollection();

    parent::__construct($resource);
}

/**
 * Transform the resource collection into an array.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($request): array
{
    $this->pagination['data'] = $this->collection;

    return [
        $this->pagination
    ];
}
```